# How to delete an element from Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I try to delete a some element from Redux `store`. As I saw from other questions on SOF, the best and easly way to do this - is to use the arry `filter` method. But the problem which I fall - that method just delete all array from Redux `store`.

What is I missed? Thank you.

/* REDUCER */

```
import { ADD_TODO, DELETE_TODO } from '../Variables/Variables'

const initialState = {
    todos: []
}

function TodoApp(state, action) {
    if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
        return initialState;
    }

    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TODO:
            return Object.assign([], state, {
                todos: [
                    ...state.todos, 
                    {
                        id: action.id,
                        text: action.text
                    }
                ]
            });
        case DELETE_TODO:
            return state.todos.filter(todos => todos.id !== action.id);
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}

export default TodoApp;
```

/* CONTAINER */

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import TodoList from '../Components/TodoList/TodoList';
import { DeleteTodo } from '../Actions/AddTodo'

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    todos: state.todos
});

const mapPropsToDispatch = dispatch => {
    return {
      todoFormDelete: todo => dispatch(DeleteTodo(todo))
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, 
    mapPropsToDispatch)(TodoList)
```

/* COMPONENT */

```
import React from 'react';
import TodoIteam from '../TodoIteam/TodoIteam'

class TodoList extends React.Component {
    handleDelete = (e) => {

        let target = e.target;
        let closest = target.closest('span');

        if (!closest) { return }

        let index = closest.parentNode.getAttribute('index');
        this.props.todoFormDelete(index);
    }

    render(props) {
        return (
            <ul onClick={this.handleDelete}>{this.props.todos.map((iteam, index) =>
                <TodoIteam key={iteam.id} {...iteam} />
                )}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

export default TodoList;
```

**UPD**
/* ACTION */

```
import { ADD_TODO, DELETE_TODO } from '../Variables/Variables'

let nextTodoId = 0;

function AddTodo(text) {
    return {
        id: nextTodoId++,
        type: ADD_TODO,
        text
    }
};

function DeleteTodo(id) {
    return {
        type: DELETE_TODO,
        id
    }
};

export { AddTodo, DeleteTodo }
```

Comment: Did you tryied to set 'undefined' as value for the element at reducer?

Comment: No, what do you mean? @DanielArtola

Answer (score 0):

```
case DELETE_TODO:
    return Object.assign({}, {todos: state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.id)})
```

Comment: Does not help. State not filtered at all.

Comment: it should work. Your state is an object with a property called todos. In your reducer you are expecting the state to be an array, whereas state.todos is the actual array that has to be filtered. Can you post the action posted to your redux store using redux dev tool.

Comment: I am assuming action.id is not properly passed. Can you post the DeleteTodo(todo) action creator

Comment: So as I said your action creator expects id as parameter. DeleteTodo(id). And you are doing `dispatch(DeleteTodo(todo))` Instead do `dispatch(DeleteTodo(todo.id))`

Comment: I try as you say, but nothing happen. I also cannot figure out what is your last solution can make? Because we already pass to `container` the actual index of the clicked item by the invoke of `this.props.todoFormDelete(index);` in `presentation` component. It already get the `index`.  and DeleteTodo(todo) transmit it normaly to action as `id`....

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

The problem is in the transmitting the `action.id`. It comes into reducer like the `string` value, so the filter does not undertand how to process `digits` and `string` together.

I just wrap `parseInt(action.id)` and it start work normally.